# Angular2 Material Responsive Sidenav and flex-layout

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

Can I make my mat-sidenav responsive using opened property or open() method and flex-layout responsive api?
Like `<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" [fxFlex.xs]="sidenav.close()">`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could consider using [@angular/flex-alyout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) [ObservableMedia](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ObservableMedia) to watch for media/breakpoint changes and update the `mode` or other properties accordingly depending on the active media level. This done by subscribing to an injected `ObservableMedia` service instance and checking the active media level. You can then bind `opened` and `mode` [properties](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api) of `<md-sidenav>` via one way `[]` binding to your class properties. This logic can be put into services and/or attribute directives if needed.

Using/updating the [properties](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api) instead of applying CSS changes will ensure that the proper animations occur.

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaChange, ObservableMedia } from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent  {
  mode: string = 'side';
  opened: boolean = true;

  constructor(private media: ObservableMedia) {
    this.media.subscribe((mediaChange: MediaChange) => {
      this.mode = this.getMode(mediaChange);
      // this.opened = this.getOpened(mediaChange);
    });
  }

  private getMode(mediaChange: MediaChange): string {
    // set mode based on a breakpoint
    if (this.media.isActive('gt-sm')) {
      return 'side';
    } else {
      return 'over';
    }
  }

  // open/close as needed
  private getOpened(mediaChange: MediaChange): string { }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav" [opened]="opened" [mode]="mode">
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <p>Sidenav content</p>

    <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to handle responsiveness in the css using flex, by giving your mat-sidenav a class depending on whether its opened or closed.

```
<mat-sidenav [ngClass]="sidenav.opened ? 'sideOpened' : 'sideClosed'">
```

.css

```
    .sideOpened {
    // Handle Responsiveness
    }
    .sideClosed {
    // Handle Responsiveness
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @AlexanderStaroselsky is great but outdated/deprecated for newer versions.

As he said if you use [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) you can use MediaQueries from [responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API):

**TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaChange, MediaObserver } from '@angular/flex-layout';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
  sidenavMode: string = 'side';

  constructor(private media: ObservableMedia) {
    this.media.asObservable().subscribe((mediaChange: MediaChange[]) => {
         this.sidenavMode = this.getMode(mediaChange);
    });
  }

  private getMode(mediaChange: MediaChange[]): string {
     return this.media.isActive('gt-sm') ? 'side' : 'over';
  }

}
```

**HTML**:

```
<mat-drawer-container hasBackdrop="false">
    <mat-drawer [mode]="sidenavMode">
        Sidenav
    </mat-drawer>
    <div>
        Hello world !
    </div>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

In this example when the screen width is lower than 960px the mode will be over.